# Linearity of this integral for elementary processes

Tags: real-analysis, integration, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Related question: [The sum of two elementary processes is an elementary process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2763394/the-sum-of-two-elementary-processes-is-an-elementary-process/2764002#2764002)

We work with respect to a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\{\mathcal{F_t\}_{t\ge 0},P})$

An elementary process is of the form

\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
\xi(t) = Z_01_{\{t=0\}}+\sum_{k=1}^n Z_k1_{\{s_k<t\le t_k\}}
\end{equation}
for ${n\ge 0}$, times $0 \le s_1 < t_1 \le s_2 < t_2 \le \dots \le s_n < t_n \,$, ${\mathcal{F}_0}$-measurable random variable ${Z_0}$ and ${\mathcal{F}_{s_k}}$-measurable random variables ${Z_k}$.

The integral of an elementary process with regard to a stochastic process $X$ over a finite range $[0,t]$ is defined by

\begin{equation}
\int_0^t\xi\,dX \equiv \sum_{k=1}^nZ_k(X(t_k\wedge t)-X(s_k\wedge t)) 
\end{equation}

If we take

$$\xi_1(t) = Z_0 1_{\{t=0\}} +\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n_1} Z_k 1_{\{s_k < t \le t_k\}}$$ and $$\xi_2(t) = Y_01_{\{t=0\}}+\sum_{k=1}^{n_2} Y_k1_{\{\tilde{s}_k<t\le \tilde{t}_k\}}$$

two elementary processes, how can we show that

$$\int_0^t \xi_1 + \xi_2\,dX =\int_0^t \xi_1 \,dX + \int_0^t \xi_2\,dX$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is shown in the accepted answer to your linked question, we can find a sequence of times $0 \leq s_1 < t_1 \leq \dots \leq s_n < t_n$ such that we can represent $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ with respect to these times. This kind of refinement of the partition is usually the key when trying to prove properties about integrals involving more than one simple function.

So, without loss of generality,
\begin{align*} \xi_1(t)  =& Z_0 1_{\{t=0\}} +\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} Z_k 1_{\{s_k < t \le t_k\}}, \\ \xi_2(t) =& Y_01_{\{t=0\}}+\sum_{k=1}^{n} Y_k1_{\{s_k<t\le t_k\}}. \end{align*}
In particular, we have
$$\xi_1(t) + \xi_2(t) = (Z_0+Y_0) 1_{\{t=0\}} +\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (Z_k+Y_k) 1_{\{s_k < t \le t_k\}}.$$
So we have
\begin{align*}
\int_0^t \xi_1 + \xi_2\,dX =& \sum_{k=1}^n (Z_k+Y_k)(X(t_k\wedge t)-X(s_k\wedge t))\\=& \sum_{k=1}^n Z_k(X(t_k\wedge t)-X(s_k\wedge t)) + \sum_{k=1}^n Y_k(X(t_k\wedge t)-X(s_k\wedge t)) \\=& \int_0^t \xi_1 \,dX + \int_0^t \xi_2\,dX
\end{align*}
as desired.

Comment: How can we represent $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ by the same partition ?

Comment: The partition that allows us to simultaneously represent $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ is what is constructed in the accepted answer to your other question.

Comment: The intervals $J_{k_1, k_2}$ there are of the form $(s_{k_1,k_2}, t_{k_1,k_2}]$ and allow the simultaneous representation of both of $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ since e.g. $I_{k,1} = \bigcup_{k_2} J_{k_1, k_2}$ where the $J_{k_1, k_2}$ are disjoint (proceed similarly for $I_{k,2}$).

Comment: This is what I would like to prove properly. That having a more refined partition doesn't affect the elementary process. How can I write that ? It is not technically showed in the other post, as we only showed that the refined partition is good for the sum of the elementary processes.

Comment: Now I use the notation from the other question. If you understand that answer then this is really no different since the point there is to construct a refined partition so that you can just add up the $Z_{k_1}$ and $Y_{k_2}$.  Explicitly, when $W_{k_1,k_2} = Z_{k_1} + Y_{k_2}$ instead set $W_{k_1,k_2} = Z_{k_1}$ and check that $\xi_1(t) = \sum_{k_1=1}^{n_1}\sum_{k_2=1}^{n_2}W_{k_1,k_2}\mathbf 1_{J_{k_1,k_2}}\left(t\right)$. Now do the same thing with $Y_{k_2}$ to get a representation of $\xi_2$ with respect to the same partition.